# Cannot resolve to a variable

Tags: java, string, variables, stream

Ok, so, im having trouble with this program im writing, it all seems to work, except this one last thing, it keeps saying that it cannot resolve   compute to a variable. heres my code. I need to make the string compute be displayed onto the window.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Mover  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {   

        String usb = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        String user = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
        File TS3S = new File(usb + "/Teamspeak 3");
        File TS3D = new File(user + "/TS3");
        File MinecraftLauncherS = new File(usb + "/Minecraft");
        File MinecraftLauncherD = new File(user);
        File ShortcutS = new File(usb + "/Shortcuts");
        File ShortcutD = new File(user);
        File MinecraftFilesS = new File(usb + "/minecraft files");
        File MinecraftFilesD = new File(user + "/Application Data");

        //make sure source exists
        if(!TS3S.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //just exit
           System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(TS3S,TS3D);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //error, just exit
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        //make sure source exists
        if(!MinecraftLauncherS.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //just exit
           System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(MinecraftLauncherS,MinecraftLauncherD);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //error, just exit
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        //make sure source exists
        if(!ShortcutS.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //just exit
           System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(ShortcutS,ShortcutD);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //error, just exit
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        //make sure source exists
        if(!MinecraftFilesS.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //just exit
           System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(MinecraftFilesS,MinecraftFilesD);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //error, just exit
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }


        System.out.println("Done");
        Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (user + "/TS3/ts3client_win32.exe");
        System.exit(0);
        }

    public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
        throws IOException{

        if(src.isDirectory()){

            //if directory not exists, create it
            if(!dest.exists()){
               dest.mkdir();
               System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                              + src + "  to " + dest);
            }

            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = src.list();

            for (String file : files) {
               //construct the src and dest file structure
               File srcFile = new File(src, file);
               File destFile = new File(dest, file);
               //recursive copy
               copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            }

        }else{
            //if file, then copy it
            //Use bytes stream to support all file types
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                   out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);

                //read it with BufferedReader
                BufferedReader br
                    = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String compute;
                while ((compute = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(compute);
                }
        }
    }
private static void createWindow() {

   //Create and set up the window. 
   JFrame a = new JFrame("Processing....");
   a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

   JLabel b = new JLabel(compute,SwingConstants.CENTER); 
   b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100)); 
   a.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

   //Display the window. 
   a.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
   a.pack();
   a.setVisible(true); 
}

public static void window(String[] args) {

   createWindow();

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring compute as a local variable in the copyFolder() function but using it in createWindow function, so it is out of scope in the createWindow function

You can make it a class level variable and do a new of your class to get an instance instead of accessing the methods statically

```
public class Mover  {

    //make it public if you want to access it directly from an instance (object)
    //of this class (myMover), else keep it private - it will be accessible only
    //in this class
    //you could also make it static but that will have limitations (can be accessed
    //only from static functions and value will be shared by all objects of this class
    public String compute;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {   
       //an object of this class needs to be created only if compute is non-static
       Mover myMover = new Mover();

       //access compute variable using myMover.compute

       // invoke your methods using myMover.copyFolder() etc
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I go about doing that? Im still relatively new to the language, so, I'll need some example code.

Comment: cant I just add static String compute; after public class Mover { ?

Comment: yes you can but you gotta be careful with it. It becomes a class level variable as opposed to instance (object) level variable and only static methods can access static variables so you may end up in spaghetti code. Also note that if you have 2 instances of Mover objects they will share the same compute variable - you may not want that

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
JLabel b = new JLabel(compute,SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

compute is not declared!!!

Comment: Depends on what you want. You can try declaring it globally to start with. Then you can always modify it in the method copyFolder.

Comment: So to declare it globally what do I need to add?